# appcompact-v7/23.1.1 values error

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

Не знаю, как мне ещё это назвать. Было ещё вчера у меня рабочее приложение, решил я к нему добавить `ScrollingActivity`, потом, пока оно полчаса добавлялось, я уже передумал, но всё-таки дождался, пока все процессы завершатся. Потом нажал Ctrl+Z, опять дождался, всё вроде отменилось. Я перезапустил студию(иногда делаю так, она от этого у меня работает быстрее). И тут на тебе! 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я опешил, пулей  в гугл, там говорят, у меня что-то устарело, но мне кажется, проблема не в этом. Ничего, в общем не нашёл, но подумал, что может это у меня студия наернулась. Запускаю другое рабочее приложение - та же самая ошибка! Ну тогда я решил, что правильно думаю и что студию надо бы переустановить, и глядишь оно всё заработает. Лёг, значит, спать. Просыпаюсь, ошибки во втором приложении больше нет, а в первом осталась! Ну что это такое?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Я удалил студию, скачал версию 1.5, установил, создал в ней новый проект, открыл в блокноте каждый файл, который я менял в своём приложении на прошлой версии AS, скопировал  всё оттуда и вставил в соответствующие новые файлы в новой AS, запустил и то же самое! Как всё могло так внезапно сломаться?  чертовщина говорю же!
**P.S.**
При установке выдал ошибку failed to install 23, я нажал retry, ошибка пропала, но решилась ли она я так и не понял. Гуглил по ней, но ничего не нашёл. Чертовщина!

Вот мой build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.studio.morpheus.morpheusholodos"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибок в тело вопроса. Дайте вопросу нормальное описательное название.

Comment: Вызывайте священника, а лучше экзорциста! А если серьезно, то проблема в варсии `android-support-v4` и `androi-support-v7` библиоткет. Что-то не совпадает с версией `targetSDK`, `build tools`, и т. п.

Comment: @metalurgus , что не совпадает? И почему поначалу совпадало, а потом вдруг перестало? И что ж делать то?

Comment: @KromStern , исправил.

Comment: Если я студию переустановлю, всё заработает??

Comment: Попробуйте студию обновить до 1.5.1

Comment: выложите сюда свой `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ошибка вызвана некоей особой строкой, содержащей спец символы и хранящейся в вашем `strings.xml` в папке `res/values`, как и говорит вам компилятор.

Он же вам и говорит путь решения проблемы:

Вам надо либо найти проблеммную строку в `strings.xml` либо не искать и каждой строке, определённой в этом файле добавить аттрибут `formatted` со значение `false`. Т.е. все ваши строки/массивы строк в `strings.xml` должны выглядеть как-то так:

```
<resources>
    <string name="some_string_name" formatted="false">some string with some speshial chars<string>
</resources>
```

---

**P.S.**
остальные ошибки вызваны вот этой первой и должны исчезнуть после означенных выше действий.